# Validation not functioning properly for double C++

Tags: c++, validation, double

I am trying to validate input for a double data type, I have succeed partly as it will output an error message if the first thing the user inputs is a letter, however if the user inputs a number at the beginning then the program accepts it, although it shouldn't. Any ideas on how to fix this? Here's my code so far:

```
void circleArea(double pi)                                                          
{
    double radius = 0.0;
    bool badInput;

    do
    {
        cout << "*================*\n";
        cout << " Area of a circle\n";
        cout << "*================*\n\n";
        cout << "Please enter the radius of your circle (numerics only):\n\n";
        cin >> radius;

        badInput = cin.fail();
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    } while (badInput == true);

    system("CLS");
    cout << "The area of your Circle is:\n\n" << radius*radius*pi << "cm^2" << endl << endl;    
    exitSystem();
}
```

Comment: _"however if the user inputs a number at the beginning then the program accepts it, although it shouldn't"_ Can you elaborate about this? `double` values take numbers naturally?

Comment: Okay, so if the input is something like "5bffhds" (number as the first thing) then the program will not consider it as failed cin, whereas it is. The validation works fine if the input is something like "gfsd3fdj" .

Comment: Parse the input into string chunks, and use `stod()` for conversion.

Comment: You need to read the whole line with std::cin.getline, and then convert it to double afterwards.

Comment: Incidentally, taking `pi` as an argument to `circleArea` seems absolutely crazy to me.

Comment: @MartinBonner I'm creating a program where I am reusing pi, hence why I am passing it to different functions and this is just one of them.

Comment: This is one of the cases where a global constant is appropriate.

Comment: Anyway, I have converted the string to a double, however what should be used to check whether the string is actually a integer type?

Comment: One option to do input validation is to use regular expressions! For instance, those of boost: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 0):

A typical idiom is to read the value in an `if` statement:

```
cout << "*================*\n";
cout << " Area of a circle\n";
cout << "*================*\n\n";
cout << "Please enter the radius of your circle (numerics only):\n\n";
if (!(cin >> radius))
{
  cerr << "Invalid input, try again.\n";
}
else
{
  // radius is valid
}
```

This does not handle the case of a number followed by a letter or invalid symbols, such as "1.23A" or "1#76".  For these cases, you will have to read the text in as a string and perform more detailed parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, use regular expressions to check whether the string that is inputted is a string!

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

const boost::regex is_number_regex("^\\d+(()|(\\.\\d+)?)$");
//If I didn't make a mistake this regex matches positive decimal numbers and integers
int main()
{
    double radius;
    std::string inputstring;
    std::cin >> inputstring;
    boost::smatch m;
    if( boost::regex_search(inputstring, m, is_number_regex))
    {
        radius = boost::lexical_cast<double>( inputstring );
        std::cout <<"Found value for radius:  "<< radius << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Error" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Adapt the regex if you need negative numbers, scientific numbers, ...